# How to query '%' character using LIKE operator in Cassandra 3.7?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, cql3, datastax-search

I use Cassandra 3.7 and have a text column with SASI index.
Let's assume that I want to find column values that contain '%' character somewhere in the middle.
The problem is that '%' is a command char for LIKE clauses.
How to escape '%' char in a query like `LIKE '%%%'`?

Here is a test script:

```
DROP keyspace if exists kmv;
CREATE keyspace if not exists kmv WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':'1'} ;
USE kmv;
CREATE TABLE if not exists kmv (id int, c1 text, c2 text, PRIMARY KEY(id, c1));
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX ON kmv.kmv  ( c2 ) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {
'analyzed' : 'true',
'analyzer_class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer',
'case_sensitive' : 'false', 
'mode' : 'CONTAINS'
};  

INSERT into kmv (id, c1, c2) values (1, 'f22', 'qwe%asd');  
SELECT c2 from kmv.kmv where c2 like '%$$%$$%';
```

The select query returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the $$ syntax to achieve this.  Your where clause would be:

LIKE '%$$%$$%'

Source: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/escape_char_r.html

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The query still returns no results.  
P.S. I've added a test script to the question.

Comment: Aww, perfect.  I'll mess around with this schema if I have time today and change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The percent sign is treated as special characters only at the beginning and the end. So `LIKE '%%%'` works fine for your case.

```
cqlsh:kmv> SELECT c2 from kmv.kmv where c2 like '%%%';

 c2
----------
 qwe%asd
```

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.7/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql3/restrictions/SingleColumnRestriction.java#L744), however, I don't think there is a way to escape the percent sign if it's the first or the last character, which means you can't do like queries to find values that start with `%`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Rather strange limitations. I guess it is either bugs or should be mentioned in official docs if it's an expected behaviour.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12573
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12621